# What’s the name of this insect that looks like a leaf? I found it in Taiwan

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

Found it in a tea plantation. It can jump.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears to be a *Tituria planata* nymph.

[image]

The adults look like this:

[image]

At first I thought it was a treehopper, but it turns out that it was a leafhopper (they are similar but different).

*Tituria planata* is one of the most common leafhopper species in Taiwan.

https://www.inaturalist.org/observations?place_id=7887&taxon_id=49025&view=species

[Image source 1](https://blog.xuite.net/mbbrgs/twblog1?st=c&w=4747385&p=3)

[Image source 2](http://www.creek.idv.tw/644.htm)